# Perfect map preserves paracompactness property

Tags: general-topology

This is an interesting problem about perfect map and paracompactness but it stucked me for a long time. Hope some one can help me solve this.

> > Let $p: X \to Y$ be a perfect map.
> >     
> > $(a)$ Show that if $Y$ is paracompact , so is $X$.
> >     
> > $(b)$ Show that if $X$ is paracompact Hausdorff space, then so is $Y$.

Thanks so much

Comment: @CamiloArosemena: A perfect map is a continuous closed surjective mapping such that $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact in $X$ for every $y \in Y$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both cases we come to a point where we wish to obtain a cover of $Y$ by means of a cover of $X.$
For a set $A$ of $X$ define $$g(A)=\{y\in Y\mid f^{-1}(y)\subseteq A\}=Y-f[X-A]$$
If $A$ is open, then so is $g(A)$ by closedness of $f.$ Also if $\mathcal U=\{U_i\mid i\in I\}$ is an open cover of $X,$ then since fibers are compact, $$\left\{g\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n U_{i_k}\right)\mid n\in\Bbb N, i_k\in I\right\}$$ is an open cover of $Y.$

Here's a solution for ($a$): Let $Y$ be paracompact and $\mathcal U=\{U_i\mid i\in I\}$ an open cover of $X.$ Then the above is an open cover of $Y,$ which has a locally finite open refinement $\mathcal V=\{V_j\mid j\in J\}.$ The preimages $f^{-1}(V_j)$ form a locally finite open cover of $X.$ Still, we dont have $f^{-1}(V_j)\subset U_i$, but rather $f^{-1}(V_j)\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^n U_{i_k},$ so in order to make it a refinement, we split each preimage by intersecting it with $U_{i_1},...,U_{i_n}.$ Since each $f^{-1}(V_j)$ is split into a finite number of open sets, the local finiteness is still satisfied. $\square$

Next, to show that $X$ Hausdorff implies $Y$ Hausdorff, let $x$ and $y$ be distinct point in $Y.$ The compact preimages $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f^{-1}(y)$ can be separated by disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ since compact sets behave like points in a Hausdorff space. Then $g(U)$ contains $x$ and $g(V)$ contains $y$ and both are open and disjoint.

Comment: Part $(b)$ is theorem 20.12 in Willard's *General Topology*.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena: Thanks. Is the Hausdorffness used for the preservation of paracompactness?

Comment: The proof relies on an article by E.Michael, "A note on paracompact spaces",*Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* 4, 831-838

Comment: And to prove $(b)$ it is only required that $X$ is $T_1$ and that $f$ is onto, closed and continuous

Comment: E. Michael in the above paper defines paracompactness so that it includes Hausdorffness. I don't know whether $X$ being T1 suffices to show that closed continuous mappings preserve paracompactness, but the proof does not seem to be in that paper. (Yes, digging graves here:p)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer solved (a). Here's a solution to (b). I will quote theorems and previous exercices in Munkres.

$X$ is paracompact Hausdorff, and therefore regular (in fact normal) by Theorem 41.1. Since $p: X \rightarrow Y$ is a perfect map, $Y$ is regular by the result of Exercise 7 of §31.

For a regular space $X$, paracompactness is equivalent to following, as per Lemma 41.3.

> Every open covering of $X$ has a refinement that is a closed covering of $X$ and locally ﬁnite.

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be an open covering of $Y$. $\mathcal{U} \equiv \{p^{-1}(V)\}_{V \in \mathcal{V}}$ is an open covering of $X$ because $p$ is continuous and surjective. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a refinement of $\mathcal{U}$ and that $\mathcal{B}$ is a closed covering of $X$ and locally finite.

We want to prove $\mathcal{C} \equiv \{p(B)\}_{B \in \mathcal{B}}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{V}$ and that $\mathcal{C}$ is a closed covering of $Y$ and locally finite.

Refinement and closedness are obvious as $p$ is closed. To prove local finiteness, notice that for any $y \in Y$, $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact (because $p$ is perfect). We can cover $p^{-1}(y)$ by finite union of open sets, each of which intersects a finite number of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. Take this finite union to be $M$. $M$ is open. We want to show $N \equiv Y - p(X-M)$ is a neighborhood of $y$ that intersects a finite number of elements of $\mathcal{C}$.

$N$ is obviously a neighborhood of $y$. If $y' \in N$, $p^{-1}(y')$ must not intersect $X-M$. Therefore $p^{-1}(y') \subset M$ and hence $p^{-1}(N) \subset M$. (This is a general property of set theory.) Since $M$ intersects a finite number of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, $N$ can only intersect a finite number of elements of $\mathcal{C}$.